# How to check duplicate cell?

Tags: java, jsp

I have imported my excel file but i want to check duplicate cells in excel sheet .

I want to check each cell read and duplicate cell display alert message in jsp page.

```
Iterator obj = new Itertor();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(obj.hasNext()) {  
    Row myrow = (ROW) obj.next();  
    class obj1 = new class();
    obj1.setname();
}
```

Comment: no . i am not using excel apache poi. general java class to iterator looping passing each cell like if(myrow.getcell(0)!=null){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your data structure. Are you using Apache POI? How are you obtaining the values from excel?

To identify duplicates create a HashSet and start adding values to the set. Add method returns true if the value was added. False otherwise.

```
Iterator sheetInterator = new Itertor();
Set<Object> set = new HashSet();
while(sheetInterator.hasNext()) { 
    Row myrow = (Row) obj.next();
    Iterator rowIterator = myrow.iterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = (Cell) rowIterator.next();
        String value = cell.getValue();
        if(!set.add(value)){
            // value has not been added to the set -> it is at least 2nd occurrence of this value 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have class object and field setter and getter method which is set the particular field in that i have to read each cell in excel file which is duplicate cell alert message displayed

Comment: @sameer I am glad I helped you with your problem.